# How to manipulate multiple object json data into table in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a simple json data, I need to populate it on table, based on condition.I can able to populate, but only first object is rendering. My json data is like

```
{ "3": {"test": {"id":1, "name":"cat"}},
  "4": {"test": {"id":2, "name":"dog"}}
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Here is my code:

home.component.html

```
<div>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="2">
        <tr *ngFor = "let x of data2">
            <td>{{x.id}}</td>
            <td>{{x.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';

declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    imageSource :any;
    statusdata1: any;
    statusdata2:any;
    closeResult: string;
    registerForm: FormGroup;
    submitted = false;
    webSocketEndPoint: string = 'wss://echo.websocket.org/';
    topic: string = "/topic/greetings";
    stompClient: any;
    mySocketData:any;
    data1:any = [];
    data2:any = [];

    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        let statusdata2 = {"3":{"test":{"id":1,"name":"cat"}},"4":{"test":{"id":2,"name":"dog"}}}

        if(statusdata2[3]) {
            this.data2.push(statusdata2[3].test);
            console.log(statusdata2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML Template you are iterating on `data2`

```
 <tr *ngFor = "let x of data2">
 <td>{{x.id}}</td>
 <td>{{x.name}}</td>
```

This means that `x` should look something like this (according to your code):

```js
let statusdata2 = {"3":{"test":{"id":1,"name":"cat"}},"4":{"test":{"id":2,"name":"dog"}}};
console.log('data2', statusdata2[3]);
```

This means that instead of `x.id` you actually need `x.test.id`. The same goes for `name`. You want `x.test.name` instead of `x.name`

Try this instead:

```
 <tr *ngFor = "let x of data2">
 <td>{{x.test.id}}</td>
 <td>{{x.test.name}}</td>
```

Comment: I removed this.data2.push(statusdata2[3].test) and used your code ,now table itself not showing

Comment: What is your error? Please remember to upvote/mark as answer

Comment: I am using html same you said and this one if(statusdata2[3]){
  //this.data2.push(statusdata2[3].test);
  console.log(statusdata2);
 }   but table is not showing in my page,I am not getting any error

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz of your issue? Please remember to upvote/mark as answer if you want further assistance

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txkvqu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Please check now

Comment: Here's your updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txkvqu You didn't implement the exact same code in your stackblitz originally so I added it.

Comment: I think you have not saved ..still same error getting

Comment: My bad: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i325ah?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: You need to change your code to accommodate that. You are working with an *object* whereas you need it to be an *array* Try mapping your objects into an array and use that.

Comment: That only I am not getting how to do

Comment: I would suggest creating another question since that's a different issue.